# Not able to wakeup after suspend on an HP 430

Tags: 11.10, hp, suspend-resume

I installed 11.10 (32-bit) with all the updates on HP 430 NoteBook. Everything works fine except the supsend/resume option. The NoteBook goes into suspension, but does not resume back when I press the power or any other button.

I don't know where to start debugging the problem. Could someone provide me pointers?

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start debugging this is the [community wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend).

Some general pointers:

1. Some suspend issues are due to buggy BIOS's - incorrect ACPI information is being passed to the kernel and thus preventing resume.
2. Some BIOS's need to have their "S3" setting enabled - *S3: Suspend to RAM* - it is worth having a look through the bios settings for a similarly named option.
3. Have a look at the [MythTV ACPI wiki](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup) - some useful reading there.  You may or may not `pm-utils` package.
4. Have a look at the suspend log to see if there are any obvious errors or issues: `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`
5. There are some good comments on *Code-Central* for a [potential solution](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug) for some laptops - looking through the comments, some people have reported that the solution there works for 11.10 users.
6. Whilst not undertaken likely - look at the HP website for [your BIOS release notes](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5086733&swItem=ob-92987-1&prodNameId=5086734&swEnvOID=4053&swLang=13&taskId=135&mode=4&idx=3).  Good manufacturers such as HP regularly issue BIOS updates.  If the release notes mention hibernate/suspend issues, then maybe a BIOS update will resolve your issue